# displayin photo library in iPad

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

this is my code to display photo library from iPad using UIPopoverController.
It gives an error saying wrong selector was passed to an instance.

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    [imagpicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
else{

    [imagpicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}
[imagpicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
[imagpicker setDelegate:self];
self.po=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagpicker];
//self.po.delegate=self;
[po setDelegate:self];

[[self po] presentPopoverFromRect:image.bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: please show the error code

Answer (score 0):

hi if you want to do it without using UIPopoverController then
please try this code.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        [imagpicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }
    else{

        [imagpicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }
    [imagpicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
    [imagpicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:imagpicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

hope this will help you.